# Reducing memory usage of MySQL

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, database, innodb

**Conclusion:**

- if you really want to use little memory out-of-the-box drop **MySQL** and use **PostgreSQL**: it has a **~30Mo** memory footprint, i.e. more than **10x** less than **MySQL**; the migration was quite easy be it the server side or application side (using NHibernate).
- in real-life of course you will not be changing your database for saving 300Mo but as noticed in the comments you will instead buy some RAM or sign up for a bigger VM if you are hosted.

---

I have a new **MySQL** setup on a **small Windows Server 2008 machine** (less than **1GB RAM**).

The **mysqld** process is consuming between **300MB** and **400MB** of memory causing the system to swap!

I've read this could help :

- disabling **InnoDB** but I need it,
- **tuning InnoDB** but my setup seems to use already low values (e.g. for **innodb_buffer_pool_size**).

For information here is the **my.ini** configuration file:

```
[client]
no-beep
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\"
datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\"
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="my-pc.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="my-pc.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="my-pc.err"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=1M
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=3M
thread_cache_size=9
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=5M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=0
read_rnd_buffer_size=0
sort_buffer_size=0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_autoextend_increment=64M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=70
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4110
query_cache_type=1
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

This MySQL server could be really small: **max 20 connections** at the same time, no more than **2GB of data** to store, **no need for high performance**...

Is there any way of reducing the memory footprint of this MySQL instance or is it already at the bare minimum?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your memory usage is _below_ the bare minimum for a 2GB InnoDB database. I would expect poor performance unless you gave it more memory to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and clear answer :) To be completely honest I'm not really sure I "need" it: what important features will I lose by disabling it? e.g. data consistency is important in this case.

Comment: RAM is cheap. Go buy some.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you on this point (+1) :), but this is an hosted virtual server: more RAM means the superior VM with more fees and this is not cheap anymore ;) I'll try to disable InnoDB and see if I get in troubles, or better I'll look for a less avid DBMS.

Comment: GET MORE MEMORY! (i.e. look at the tradeoff in the cost of low performance ... bad Customer Service, poor user response, bad sales to that of the increase in memory).  Have you thought of going to another provider that has more favorable cloud rates?

Comment: @mdpc: you're right but I'm doing some testing so I'm trying to limit costs; be ensured this is not the kind of question I'd be asking for a production system ;) But this is an instructive process, I will post a small feedback soon...

Answer (score 4):

The following my.ini for mysql 5.6 causes the "private bytes" to go from 630MB down to 20MB and the "working set" from 450MB down to 21MB on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  The performance of a mysql server configured like this is probably going to be very bad, but technically, if you want it to occupy as little memory as possible, then this is the answer.

```
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
[client]
no-beep
socket=0.0
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
# server_type=3
[mysqld]
# skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory
# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL
socket=MYSQL
port=3306
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/"
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
# plugin-load=authentication_windows.dll
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="PEGASUS.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="PEGASUS-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
# log-bin
log-error="PEGASUS.err"
server-id=1
max_connections=20 
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=100
tmp_table_size=44M
thread_cache_size=0
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=1M
key_buffer_size=8
read_buffer_size=8K
read_rnd_buffer_size=8K
sort_buffer_size=32K
# innodb_data_home_dir=0.0
# skip-innodb
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=1M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_concurrency_tickets=10
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=10
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=5
flush_time=10
join_buffer_size=16K
max_allowed_packet=1M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=100
query_cache_type=2
table_definition_cache=400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
host_cache_size=0
thread_stack=128K
max_heap_table_size=16K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
binlog_cache_size=4K
binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K
performance_schema=0
```

Taken from here: [michael.gr - Minimal MySQL Memory Footprint](http://blog.michael.gr/2015/03/minimal-mysql-memory-footprint.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing *Mike*, hopefully it will help someone with this issue. As for me I've upgraded. :)

Comment: Yes, I posted it for the sake of future generations!

Comment: Reduced memory footprint from 480MB to 45MB, thanks. However that increased our test suite execution by about 10% (just be aware that there is some possible drawbacks)

Comment: @RomualdBrunet thank you for reporting this.  A 10% slow-down is actually far better than I suspected.